# Clarification on filing Tax for the education expenses?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

Last year i spent around $1200 on preparing GRE through Kaplan. Whether that expense can be declared in filing Tax?

Second question is, I am from Computer Programming background and going back to school as Part Time student to do Master's in Statistics Grad Program. Whether that expense will be considered for any waiver while filing the tax for the next year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Test fees in general are not deductible from your taxes. You can only deduct [qualified education expenses](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/College/Deduction-for-Higher-Education/INF12002.html):

> Qualified expenses include what you pay in tuition and mandatory
>   enrollment fees to attend any accredited public or private institution
>   above the high school level.
>
> You cannot take a deduction for:
>
> - Room and board, optional fees (such as for student health insurance), transportation, or other similar personal expenses.
> - Course-related books and supplies, unless you are required to buy    them directly from the school.
> - Any course involving sports, games or hobbies, unless it’s part of    the degree program.

Comment: Thank you @Michael, That helps.. Just on curious .. I mentioned that my background and job is a programmer.. now, i am going to do Graduation program in a different field .. Is it still be okay .. irrespective of whatever graduation program , i am going for .. can also be considered to be Tax deductible ..

Comment: You can deduct qualified educational expenses regardless of your professional background. You could be a rocket scientist pursuing education part-time in underwater basket weaving and still deduct qualifying educational expenses.